# Python alias/pointer file creation

Tags: python, directory

I have multiple directories that require the same large `json` file. Rather than storing the `json` file multiple times, I would like to store it in one directory and create an `alias` that points to the actual file in the other directories.

How do I create a shortcut/alias for a file in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a symlink to the file. In python this looks like:

```
import os
os.symlink("my_json_file.json", "the_link");
```